# Swiper 7 CSS is not applied when imported

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I installed Swiper on a React app as the documentation says I did:

```
import "swiper/css";
```

and then:

```
  <Swiper
    spaceBetween={50}
    slidesPerView={3}
    onSlideChange={() => console.log("slide change")}
    onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
  >
    <SwiperSlide>1</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>2</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>3</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>4</SwiperSlide>
  </Swiper>
```

But the styles are not being applied to the Swiper and it is not working.

Comment: do you import `swiper/css` on top of the component that uses `Swiper`?

Comment: Also, do you use any CSS post/pre processor?

Answer (score 0):

```
@import 'swiper/swiper.scss';

//optional
@import 'swiper/components/navigation/navigation.scss';
@import 'swiper/components/pagination/pagination.scss';
@import 'swiper/components/scrollbar/scrollbar.scss';
```

Comment: I have tried that, then it complains that these modules are not exported

Comment: Package path ./swiper.scss is not exported from package C:\Users\...\node_modules\swiper

Comment: Can you try this => npm i swiper --save or yarn add swiper --save

Comment: I have tried, no difference.